# Adding clickable circle in bokeh plots

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I am trying to add certain callbacks to a circles which are plotted on bokeh plot. Each circle is associated with certain record from columndatasource. I want to access that record whenever corresponding circle is clicked. Is there any way to add callbacks to circles in bokeh?
How can i do it?

I am using following code

```
fig =figure(x_range=(-bound, bound), y_range=(-bound, bound),
                plot_width=800, plot_height=500,output_backend="webgl")

fig.circle(x='longitude',y='latitude',size=2,source=source,fill_color="blue",
                fill_alpha=1, line_color=None)
```

Comment: JavaScript callbacks? or Python callbacks? The latter would require a bokeh server app.

Comment: python callbacks

Answer (score 2):

Then you want to add an `on_change` callback to the `selected` property of the data source. Here is a minimal example. As stated above, python callbacks require the Bokeh server (that is where python callbacks actually get run, since the browser knows nothing of python), so this must be run e.g. `bokeh serve --show example.py` (Or, if you are in a notebook, following the pattern in [this example notebook](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb)).

```
# example.py

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,6,5]))

p = figure(title="select a circle", tools="tap")
p.circle('x', 'y', size=25, source=source)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # This uses syntax for Bokeh >= 0.13
    print("Indices of selected circles: ", source.selected.indices)

source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Comment: Please include JavaScript callbacks example too.

Comment: That's a different question, so it should go in a new, different SO question.

Comment: Also, there are lots of examples of JS callbacks in the docs: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I copied the above example, started it with `bokeh serve clickable_circle.py`. I do see the plot and I can select individual circles, but there are no print statements. I am using Bokeh server version 1.1.0.

Comment: I've updated the answer for 0.13 or newer. There was actually an API mistake in 0.12.15 that has since been corrected. Bokeh will now only ever change properties on a selection, it will never change a selection object itself. This fact, and the callback functionality are now maintained under new continuous integration tests.